# Create an object of another class python

Tags: python, object

So I have 1 package student with one class Student and I have a main.py outside that package and I'm trying to create an object of Student example

```
class Student:
    Id=""

    def __init__(self, Id):
        self.Id = Id
```

Separate File main.py:

```
 def main():
        print("is workign")
        temp =  Student("50")  ## I want to create the object of class Student and send an attribute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I hope your indents aren't actually that bad.

Comment: you need to import the student in your main.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the class defined outside of your code, the class needs to be imported. Assume main.py and student.py are in the same folder:

> student.py

```
class Student:
    Id=""

    def __init__(self, Id):
        self.Id = Id
```

> main.py

```
def main():
    from student import Student
    print("is workign")
    temp =  Student("50")  ## I want to create the object of class Student and send an attribute

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What if the student class in in a sub sub-directory? because I have a different package so the student.py is in another folder called object

Comment: from subdic1.subdic2.student import Student